# having trouble setting up flutter in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have trouble in setting flutter and running an app on a real device in vs code. I want to run my apps on physical device and I do not want to use emulators. Is it going to be possible?

Comment: You didnt say what is causing your troubles. We dont know what you been trying, what works and what doesnt. Please give some more information instead of just saying you are having troubles.

Comment: For sure, I installed the vs code latest version. Then I installed flutter and as well as flutter and dart extensions in vs code. Actually I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very possible. In fact, many flutter developers use physical devices in order to test features like Maps,Camera, etc. I always recommend following a video tutorial to set up environments for development. But you should try the following:

> First of all, I recommend the flutter docs https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code to set up vscode.

After this, all you need does not have anything to do with VSCode any longer. You should check https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows to connect a physical device.

Comment: I installed the vs code latest version. Then I installed flutter and as well as flutter and dart extensions in vs code. Actually I do not know what to do next. Please help me!

Comment: I installed the vs code latest version. Then I installed flutter and as well as flutter and dart extensions in vs code. Actually I do not know what to do next. Please help me!

Comment: Do you have Android studio installed? You have to follow the steps from the doc https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows or maybe watch a recent tutorial on Youtube on how to setup vscode for flutter.. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=visual+studio+code+flutter+   I mean you have so many options to choose from

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you have already setup flutter on your machine to start with. If you haven't use this link [how to install flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

the next part is easy just install `dart` and `flutter` extensions in vscode.
walla!